# .SRT Captions not Playing in IE11

Tags: html5-video, closed-captions

Any ideas why .srt files are not playing in IE11 and Chrome. I have encoded the files as UTF8. I also added the mime type on my server to text/srt. I also get the error Text Track: Unknown MIME type. hr=8007000b. in cosole.

`1
00:00:22,000 --> 00:00:27,000
I'll teach thee Bugology, Ignatzes`

2 
00:00:40,000 --> 00:00:43,000 
Something tells me

3 
00:00:58,000 --> 00:01:59,000 
Look, Ignatz, a sleeping bee

Answer (score 1):

SRT sub-title files are not supported in HTML5 out of the box.

You must include/convert it to a [WebVTT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API) file.

Then you'd use the `<track>` element to include it with your video source, for example:

```
<video id="video" controls preload="metadata">
   <source src="video/sintel-short.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="video/sintel-short.webm" type="video/webm">
   <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="vtt/sintel-en.vtt" default>
   <track label="Deutsch" kind="subtitles" srclang="de" src="vtt/sintel-de.vtt">
   <track label="Español" kind="subtitles" srclang="es" src="vtt/sintel-es.vtt">
</video>
```

See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video) for more details.

Comment: Thanks my client is saying that they have .srt  caption files playing in IE 11 web browser from other vendors. I originally had the captions as a WebVTT file, which works fine but not acceptable to customer.